# EXT4 on USB - how to specify journalling behaviour to be same as for root disk partitions

Tags: configuration, ext4, options

Please consider the prior [discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/716228/os-seems-to-apply-ext4-filesystem-options-in-arbitrary-fashion) as background to this new question.

I have modified my script and applied the same filesystem options to my USB drive's ext4 partitions using [tune2fs](/questions/tagged/tune2fs), and mount options specified in the fstab.

Those options are all the same as for the previous discussion.  I have applied those changes and performed a reboot, but the [mount](/questions/tagged/mount) command is not reporting what I would have expected, namely that it would show mount options similar to those reported for the internal hard drive partitions.  What is being reported is the following:

```
/dev/sdc3 on /site/DB005_F1 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdc4 on /site/DB005_F2 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdc5 on /site/DB005_F3 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdc6 on /site/DB005_F4 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdc7 on /site/DB005_F5 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdc8 on /site/DB005_F6 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdc9 on /site/DB005_F7 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdc10 on /site/DB005_F8 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdc11 on /site/DB006_F1 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdc12 on /site/DB006_F2 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdc13 on /site/DB006_F3 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdc14 on /site/DB006_F4 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdc15 on /site/DB006_F5 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdc16 on /site/DB006_F6 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdc17 on /site/DB006_F7 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sdc18 on /site/DB006_F8 type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

These are all reporting the same, but only reporting "rw,relatime", when I expected much more.

The full [dumpe2fs](/questions/tagged/dumpe2fs) report for the first USB partition (same as for all others) is as follows:

```
root@OasisMega1:/DB001_F2/Oasis/bin# more tuneFS.previous.DB005_F1.20220907-210437.dumpe2fs
dumpe2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
Filesystem volume name:   DB005_F1
Last mounted on:          <not available>
Filesystem UUID:          11c8fbcc-c1e1-424d-9ffe-ad0ccf480128
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_fi
le dir_nlink extra_isize metadata_csum
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    journal_data user_xattr acl block_validity nodelalloc
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Remount read-only
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              6553600
Block count:              26214400
Reserved block count:     1310720
Free blocks:              25656747
Free inodes:              6553589
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      1017
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Sat Nov  7 09:57:44 2020
Last mount time:          Wed Sep  7 18:18:32 2022
Last write time:          Wed Sep  7 20:55:33 2022
Mount count:              211
Maximum mount count:      10
Last checked:             Sun Nov 22 13:50:57 2020
Check interval:           1209600 (2 weeks)
Next check after:         Sun Dec  6 13:50:57 2020
Lifetime writes:          1607 MB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     32
Desired extra isize:      32
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      802d4ef6-daf4-4f68-b889-435a5ce467c3
Journal backup:           inode blocks
Checksum type:            crc32c
Checksum:                 0x21a24a19
Journal features:         journal_checksum_v3
Journal size:             512M
Journal length:           131072
Journal sequence:         0x000000bd
Journal start:            0
Journal checksum type:    crc32c
Journal checksum:         0xf0a385eb
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Can something be done to have both internal and USB hard disk report same options?

In my /etc/default/[grub](/questions/tagged/grub) file, I currently use the following definition involving a [quirk](/questions/tagged/quirk):

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=1 usb-storage.quirks=1058:25ee:u ipv6.disable=1"
```

Do I need to specify another quirk for the journalling and mount options to take effect as desired?  Or is this again an "**everything is OK**" situation, the same as for the other post?

Modified script:

```
#!/bin/sh

####################################################################################
###
### $Id: tuneFS.sh,v 1.3 2022/09/08 03:31:12 root Exp $
###
### Script to set consistent (local/site) preferences for filesystem treatment at boot-time or mounting
###
####################################################################################

TIMESTAMP=`date '+%Y%m%d-%H%M%S' `
BASE=`basename "$0" ".sh" `


###
### These variables will document hard-coded 'mount' preferences for filesystems
###
count=1
BOOT_MAX_INTERVAL="-c 20"   ### max number of boots before fsck [20 boots]
TIME_MAX_INTERVAL="-i 2w"   ### max calendar time between boots before fsck [2 weeks]
ERROR_ACTION="-e remount-ro"    ### what to do if error encountered
#-m reserved-blocks-percentage

###
### This OPTIONS string should be updated manually to document
### the preferred and expected settings to be applied to ext4 filesystems
###
OPTIONS="-o journal_data,block_validity,nodelalloc"


ASSIGN=0
REPORT=0
VERB=0
SINGLE=0
USB=0
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case ${1} in
        --default ) REPORT=0 ; ASSIGN=0 ; shift ;;
        --report )  REPORT=1 ; ASSIGN=0 ; shift ;;
        --force )   REPORT=0 ; ASSIGN=1 ; shift ;;
        --verbose ) VERB=1 ; shift ;;
        --single )  SINGLE=1 ; shift ;;
        --usb )     USB=1 ; shift ;;
        * ) echo "\n\t Invalid parameter used on the command line.  Valid options:  [ --default | --report | --force | --single | --usb | --verbose ] \n Bye!\n" ; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done


workHorse()
{
    reference=`ls -t1 "${PREF}."*".dumpe2fs" 2>/dev/null | tail -1 `

    if [ -n "${reference}" -a -s "${reference}" ]
    then
        if [ ! -f "${PREF}.dumpe2fs.REFERENCE" ]
        then
            mv -v ${reference} ${PREF}.dumpe2fs.REFERENCE
        fi
    fi

    reference=`ls -t1 "${PREF}."*".verify" 2>/dev/null | tail -1 `

    if [ -n "${reference}" -a -s "${reference}" ]
    then
        if [ ! -f "${PREF}.verify.REFERENCE" ]
        then
            mv -v ${reference} ${PREF}.verify.REFERENCE
        fi
    fi

    BACKUP="${BASE}.previous.${PARTITION}.${TIMESTAMP}"
    BACKUP="${BASE}.previous.${PARTITION}.${TIMESTAMP}"

    rm -f ${PREF}.*.tune2fs
    rm -f ${PREF}.*.dumpe2fs

    ### reporting by 'tune2fs -l' is a subset of that from 'dumpe2fs -h'

    if [ ${REPORT} -eq 1 ]
    then
        ### No need to generate report from tune2fs for this mode.

        ( dumpe2fs -h ${DEVICE} 2>&1 ) | awk '{
                if( NR == 1 ){ print $0 } ;
                if( index($0,"revision") != 0 ){ print $0 } ;
                if( index($0,"mount options") != 0 ){ print $0 } ;
                if( index($0,"features") != 0 ){ print $0 } ;
                if( index($0,"Filesystem flags") != 0 ){ print $0 } ;
                if( index($0,"directory hash") != 0 ){ print $0 } ;
            }'>${BACKUP}.dumpe2fs
        echo "\n dumpe2fs REPORT [$PARTITION]:"
        cat ${BACKUP}.dumpe2fs
    else
        ### Generate report from tune2fs for this mode but only as sanity check.

        tune2fs -l ${DEVICE} 2>&1 >${BACKUP}.tune2fs

        ( dumpe2fs -h ${DEVICE} 2>&1 ) >${BACKUP}.dumpe2fs

        if [ ${VERB} -eq 1 ] ; then
            echo "\n tune2fs REPORT:"
            cat ${BACKUP}.tune2fs

            echo "\n dumpe2fs REPORT:"
            cat ${BACKUP}.dumpe2fs
        fi

        if [ ${ASSIGN} -eq 1 ]
        then
            echo "  COMMAND:  tune2fs ${COUNTER_SET} ${BOOT_MAX_INTERVAL}  ${TIME_MAX_INTERVAL}  ${ERROR_ACTION}  ${OPTIONS}  ${DEVICE} ..."
            tune2fs ${COUNTER_SET} ${BOOT_MAX_INTERVAL}  ${TIME_MAX_INTERVAL}  ${ERROR_ACTION}  ${OPTIONS}  ${DEVICE}

            rm -f ${PREF}.*.verify
            ( dumpe2fs -h ${DEVICE} 2>&1 ) >${BACKUP}.verify

            if [ ${VERB} -eq 1 ] ; then  
                echo "\n Changes:"
                diff ${BACKUP}.dumpe2fs ${BACKUP}.verify
            fi
        else
            if [ ${VERB} -eq 1 ] ; then  
                echo "\n Differences:"
                diff ${BACKUP}.tune2fs ${BACKUP}.dumpe2fs
            fi

            rm -f ${BACKUP}.verify
        fi
    fi
}


workPartitions()
{
    case ${PARTITION} in
        1 ) case ${DISK_ID} in
                1 ) DEVICE="/dev/sda3"  ; OPTIONS="" ;;
                5 ) DEVICE="/dev/sdc3"  ;;
                6 ) DEVICE="/dev/sdc11" ;;
            esac ;;
        2 ) case ${DISK_ID} in
                1 ) DEVICE="/dev/sda7"  ;;
                5 ) DEVICE="/dev/sdc4"  ;;
                6 ) DEVICE="/dev/sdc12" ;;
            esac ;;
        3 ) case ${DISK_ID} in
                1 ) DEVICE="/dev/sda8"  ;;
                5 ) DEVICE="/dev/sdc5"  ;;
                6 ) DEVICE="/dev/sdc13" ;;
            esac ;;
        4 ) case ${DISK_ID} in
                1 ) DEVICE="/dev/sda9"  ;;
                5 ) DEVICE="/dev/sdc6"  ;;
                6 ) DEVICE="/dev/sdc14" ;;
            esac ;;
        5 ) case ${DISK_ID} in
                1 ) DEVICE="/dev/sda12" ;;
                5 ) DEVICE="/dev/sdc7"  ;;
                6 ) DEVICE="/dev/sdc15" ;;
            esac ;;
        6 ) case ${DISK_ID} in
                1 ) DEVICE="/dev/sda13" ;;
                5 ) DEVICE="/dev/sdc8"  ;;
                6 ) DEVICE="/dev/sdc16" ;;
            esac ;;
        7 ) case ${DISK_ID} in
                1 ) DEVICE="/dev/sda14" ;;
                5 ) DEVICE="/dev/sdc9"  ;;
                6 ) DEVICE="/dev/sdc17" ;;
            esac ;;
        8 ) case ${DISK_ID} in
                1 ) DEVICE="/dev/sda4"  ;;
                5 ) DEVICE="/dev/sdc10" ;;
                6 ) DEVICE="/dev/sdc18" ;;
            esac ;;
    esac
    PARTITION="DB00${DISK_ID}_F${PARTITION}"
    PREF="${BASE}.previous.${PARTITION}"

    echo "\n\t\t PARTITION = ${PARTITION}"
    echo "\t\t DEVICE    = ${DEVICE}"

    count=`expr ${count} + 1 `
    COUNTER_SET="-C ${count}"
    workHorse

}


workPartitionGroups()
{
    if [ ${SINGLE} -eq 1 ]
    then
        for PARTITION in `echo ${ID_SET} `
        do
            echo "\n\t Actions only for DB00${DISK_ID}_F${PARTITION} ? [y|N] => \c" ; read sel
            if [ -z "${sel}" ] ; then  sel="N" ; fi
            case ${sel} in
                y* | Y* ) DOIT=1 ; break ;;
                * ) DOIT=0 ;;
            esac
        done

        if [ ${DOIT} -eq 1 ]
        then
            #echo "\t\t PARTITION ID == ${PARTITION} ..."
            workPartitions
            exit
        fi
    else
        for PARTITION in `echo ${ID_SET} `
        do
            #echo "\t\t PARTITION ID == ${PARTITION} ..."
            workPartitions
        done
    fi
}


if [ ${USB} -eq 1 ]
then
    for DISK_ID in 5 6
    do
        echo "\n\n DISK ID == ${DISK_ID} ..."
        ID_SET="1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8"
        workPartitionGroups
    done
else
    DISK_ID="1"
    echo "\n\n DISK ID == ${DISK_ID} ..."
    ID_SET="2 3 4 5 6 7 8"
    workPartitionGroups
fi



exit 0
exit 0
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ext4 filesystem options may not take effect if specified in `/etc/fstab` as they require changes to filesystem structures. Some of those can be simply applied with `tune2fs` while the filesystem is unmounted, but there are some options that may require running a full filesystem check after `tune2fs` to take effect properly.

As far as I know, there is no mechanism that would affect filesystem options based on whether the disk is connected by USB or not.

Comment: does the fact that the dumpe2fs reports "Filesystem features" which has "journal_data" listed, does that confirm that the journal is functional and writing both data and inodes to the journal?  Does "Journal features" need to report anything more than "journal_checksum_v3" to confirm that the intended journal mode (data) is in effect?

Comment: I noticed that the script I normally use to mount partitions was not actually taking the options from the /etc/fstab.  So I've fixed that, using only mount -v -U ${UUID}, but I don't get the full set of options expected reported by mount | grep 'sdc'.  I only get "/dev/sdc3 on /site/DB005_F1 type ext4 (rw,relatime,journal_async_commit,commit=15)", which is identical for all 16 data partitions on my external USB drive.  shouldn't it report more? deguge2fs is reporting "journal_incompat_revoke journal_async_commit journal_checksum_v3" for all.

Comment: Just a general comment: why is it necessary to use different tools and look in different places to obtain a complete report of options in effect on file systems?  Has anyone considered the benefits of unifying all these file system attributes so that a clear and cohesive global view could be obtained in one fell swoop?  Maybe debuge2fs is intended for that purpose, for reporting (and it seems to do the job well enough), but isn't there some way that the front end of creating file systems provide a similar single global mechanism addressing all aspects of the filesystem as intended in situ?

Comment: As far as I understand based on a quick peek at the source code, the options listed by `mount` come from `/proc/mounts` and are ultimately determined for ext4 filesystems by the `_ext4_show_options()` function in `<kernel source>/fs/ext4/super.c`. [It seems to be rather complex.](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/ext4/super.c?h=v6.0-rc4#n2923). A comment says: "Show an option if
 it's set to a non-default value OR
 if the per-sb default is different from the global default", and that might be overall logic.

Comment: thank you for pointing me to the kernel code repository. I can't code that, but I can try to understand it and act accordingly. Does the item git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/… reflect current behaviour that ONLY non-default options are reported ? While absolutely confusing, that could potentially explain why I am not seeing explicit listing of what options are in effect. Does dumpe2fs report ALL, or only what that Kernel code reference is indicating ?

Comment: `tune2fs` and particularly `dumpe2fs` are both capable of (& designed for) handling unmounted filesystems, so they implement their option reporting independent of the kernel. They are also the tools you would turn to when you need to troubleshoot unexpected behavior by the filesystem. So I would expect them to report ALL the options. Since the ext4 filesystem is rather stable, the kernel's option reporting behavior should be essentially unchanged (maybe with some new options added over time) in all modern kernel releases.

Comment: In https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/fs/ext4?h=v6.0-rc4&id=cebe85d570cf84804e848332d6721bc9e5300e07 , it says "As a result we can't print the options to the log as we did in the past after the successful mount."  Does the update by https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/fs/ext4?h=v6.0-rc4&id=e5a185c26c11cbd1d386be8ee4c5e57b4f62273a rectify that issue, and is /proc/mount the fully-descriptive "master" or is dumpe2fs -h the "master" for filesystem state ?